Is there a way to directly change a suffix .dev in a Gateway URL for Production environment
I'm setting up a production environment on GCP using API Gateway and have run into an issue in the generated URL. Currently, the URL for my production gateway includes the .dev suffix, which can cause confusion since the .dev suffix is ​​usually associated with development environments and not production environments.
Example:
https://-<encrypt_code>..gateway.dev
My goal is to remove or modify the .dev suffix to make the URL more suitable for production
Some Solutions I have considered without success:
Setting up custom domains directly in API Gateway: I've looked into this possibility, but there doesn't seem to be a direct option to remove the .dev suffix from generated URLs.
Use a custom domain with a reverse proxy or load balancer: Although I could use a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx) or configure a Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer in GCP with a custom domain, I'm wondering if there is a better solution direct that does not involve adding this additional layer.
Explore Cloud Endpoints: I've read that Cloud Endpoints allows a little more flexibility when it comes to custom domains, but this would involve changing the current configuration and structure of my API in API Gateway.
I need help please. Some came across with this issue before?

As advised in this document, custom domain names are still not supported for API Gateway. The best way for now to customize the domain of your gateway is to configure a load balancer then direct the request to the gateway.dev domain of your deployed API.
You can also consider searching for an existing feature request similar to this issue you encountered and Star it. If you don't see any matching issue or feature request, you can create one.
